# Can´t add Emojis in Meta Title, Description - Help

Tags: magento-1.9, database, seo, character-encoding

I can't add emojis in meta titles or meta description.

On save, Magento erases emoji and text below.

My Magento version is 1.9 community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(MySQL) UTF-8 doesn't support all emojis. I guess you have to change the effected DB columns to "utf8mb4"

There is a good description on SE: [How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)

---

*Just copy&paste from there, but this is important.*

***My answer only adds to Selvamani P answer.***

You might also need to change any `SET NAMES utf8` queries with `SET NAMES utf8mb4`. That did the trick for me.

Also, [this is a great article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) to port your website from utf8 to utf8mb4. In particular the article makes 2 good points on indexes and repairing tables after converting them to utf8mb4:

**INDEXES**

> When converting from utf8 to utf8mb4, the maximum length of a column
>   or index key is unchanged in terms of bytes. Therefore, it is smaller
>   in terms of characters, because the maximum length of a character is
>   now four bytes instead of three. [...] The InnoDB storage engine has a maximum index length of 767 bytes, so for utf8 or utf8mb4 columns, you can index a maximum of 255 or 191 characters, respectively. If you currently have utf8 columns with indexes longer than 191 characters, you will need to index a smaller number of characters when using utf8mb4.

**REPAIRING TABLES**

> After upgrading the MySQL server and making the necessary changes
>   explained above, make sure to repair and optimize all databases and
>   tables. I didn’t do this right away after upgrading (I didn’t think it
>   was necessary, as everything seemed to work fine at first glance), and
>   ran into some weird bugs where UPDATE statements didn’t have any
>   effect, even though no errors were thrown.

Read more about the queries to repair tables on the article.

Btw ... this has been fixed in Magento 2.2 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12058)