# Emoji is saving as (???????) in the database Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, javascript, ajax, column

I added the Emojo library including JS and CSS files. Then it starts to display on the frontend.

When I send the Emoji character via ajax. I am getting Emoji in the param request so while saving the same emoji in the database column it is saving data like (??????) characters

Here is the code that I am using to send Emoji via Ajax request::

```
function getAjaxrequestChat() {
       
       var message = jQuery('#chat-message').val();
        if(message == ''){
            return false;
        }
        var customername ="";
        var url= "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'test/Index/chat'?>";
        
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {message:message},
            complete: function(response) {
            },
        });
   }
```

When I check data in the network of the browser it shows Emoji like() but these emoji save in the database column show value as mentioned in the screenshot below::
[image]

Can you please help me to how to save the same Emoji characters that are sent through the Ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

(MySQL) UTF-8 doesn't support all emojis. I guess you have to change the effected DB columns to "utf8mb4"

There is a good description on SE: [How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)

---

*Just copy&paste from there, but this is important.*

***My answer only adds to Selvamani P answer.***

You might also need to change any `SET NAMES utf8` queries with `SET NAMES utf8mb4`. That did the trick for me.

Also, [this is a great article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) to port your website from utf8 to utf8mb4. In particular the article makes 2 good points on indexes and repairing tables after converting them to utf8mb4:

**INDEXES**

> When converting from utf8 to utf8mb4, the maximum length of a column
> or index key is unchanged in terms of bytes. Therefore, it is smaller
> in terms of characters, because the maximum length of a character is
> now four bytes instead of three. [...] The InnoDB storage engine has a maximum index length of 767 bytes, so for utf8 or utf8mb4 columns, you can index a maximum of 255 or 191 characters, respectively. If you currently have utf8 columns with indexes longer than 191 characters, you will need to index a smaller number of characters when using utf8mb4.

**REPAIRING TABLES**

> After upgrading the MySQL server and making the necessary changes
> explained above, make sure to repair and optimize all databases and
> tables. I didn’t do this right away after upgrading (I didn’t think it
> was necessary, as everything seemed to work fine at first glance), and
> ran into some weird bugs where UPDATE statements didn’t have any
> effect, even though no errors were thrown.

Read more about the queries to repair tables on the article.

Btw ... this has been fixed in Magento 2.2 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12058)

This answer is by [sv3n](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/46249/sv3n)
Link of answer [Click](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213828/can%C2%B4t-add-emojis-in-meta-title-description-help)

Comment: I changed all the column configuration but still Emoji saving as ??? in the column table of the database.